# Problem outputting result to command line.

Tags: c#, wolfram-mathematica

```
isALeapYear[x_Integer]:= 
If[(Mod[x,4]==0 && !Mod[x,100]==0) || (Mod[x,4]==0 && Mod[x,400]==0),ToString[x] <>" is a leap year", ToString[x] <> " is NOT a leap year"]
```

Below is my attempt to solve the exercise "Leap" from Exercism.com as I struggle to teach myself C#. The site suggests coming here for help. I have already figured out the logic in Mathematica (above) but my little C# program does not return anything when I run `dotnet run` in terminal. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
using System;

public static class Leap
{
    public static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
    {
        if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 == 0) 
        {
            return true;    
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        int yearq = 2015;
        bool result = IsLeapYear(yearq);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code should work. There are no problems with the code you pasted.

Comment: Your calculation is wrong, it should be not mod 100.

Comment: I also think your static class should be called Program, but I don't have that much experience with running through the command line like that

Comment: Thanks. That's a good place to start.

Comment: in your method: return year % 4 == 0;, would be enough because this is a boolean

Comment: Note that if you want to use the main-method as the entry point it needs to start with a capital M: [Main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/)

Comment: If I capitalize "main" I get the following error "CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point." I assume I have another "Main" entry point somewhere in the solution file?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new console project in Visual Studio a file named `Program.cs` is added automatically with a static [`Main`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) method. This is the [`entry point`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#C#) of your application. The first line in the method is the line that will execute first.

It looks like this:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             // By default this line will execute first
        }
    }
}
```

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) explains it better:

> The `Main` method is the entry point of a C# application. (Libraries and
>   services do not require a `Main` method as an entry point.) When the
>   application is started, the `Main` method is the first method that is
>   invoked.
>
> There can only be one entry point in a C# program. If you have more
>   than one class that has a `Main` method, you must compile your program
>   with the /main compiler option to specify which Main method to use as
>   the entry point.

I'm guessing you did't change `Program.Main` and the program just executes and does nothing.

I suggest moving the content of your `main` method into `Program.Main`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int yearq = 2015;
    bool result = Leap.IsLeapYear(yearq);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

If however you do need to specify more than one class with a `Main` method you must tell the compiler which method to use as the entry point by using the [`-main`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/main-compiler-option) compiler option.

You also have the option of deleting `Program.cs` and renaming your `main` to `Main`, but unless you have some special need to do so I would rather go with the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the question for future prosperity, interestingly I solved my own question by adding:

```
<IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
```

...to the `PropertyGroup` of the .csproj file from [this tutorial website](https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/). Reading the page, I can't say I completely understand why it fixed my problem; hence leaving the question unanswered in case someone can better explain the answer. (It definately had something to do with the -main complier options mentioned elsewhere in the answers.)